# Joint 3 table mysql error

Tags: mysql, database, select

Hi developpers i am trying to get data from the table "etudiant" where "etudiant" and the "enseignant " have the same foreginkey of table "service"

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    etudiant
INNER JOIN etservice et1 ON
    et1.id_service = enseigant.id_service
INNER JOIN etservice ON etservice.id_service = etudiant.id_service
WHERE
    1 = 1
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the first join. It's referencing 'enseigant' but that table/view isn't specified anywhere else. Perhaps you meant:
    INNER JOIN enseigant

Comment: I didn't get it , am trying to do join without any need for an other table to save the relation .. how the code must be then !